# If $R\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, then $\operatorname{Frac}(R[\alpha])=F(\alpha)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, solution-verification

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $F=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$. Does it imply that $\operatorname{Frac}(R[\alpha]) = F(\alpha)$?

I have tried the forward inclusion as follows:

Let $z\in \operatorname{Frac}(R[\alpha])$. Then $z=\dfrac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in R[\alpha]\subseteq F(\alpha)$. Hence, $z\in F(\alpha)$.

Also, here is my attempt for the backward inclusion:

Let $z\in F(\alpha)$. Then $z=\dfrac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}$ for some polynomials $f,g\in F[x]$. Then we can write $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{a} F(x), g(x)=\dfrac{1}{b} G(x)$ where $F$ and $G$ are polynomials over $R$ and $a,b\in R$. So $z = \dfrac{bF(\alpha)}{aG(\alpha)}$. Since $bF(\alpha), aG(\alpha)\in R[\alpha]$, this proves the claim.

I'm quite sure of them but I may have missed some technicalities.

Comment: Your proof is correct. An easier method to prove that something is a fraction field is using the characterization: the fraction field of a ring $S$ is the smallest field containing $S$. Since the smallest field containing $R$ is $F$, the smallest field containing $R [ \alpha]$ is $F(\alpha)$.